# the formik form send a undefined array after the use of fieldArray

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, formik

im doing a single form that will hundle the creationa nd the update of an object
i did a condition to part the creation and update
in case the update the values are initialized by the old values using the id
and in case teh creation all values are initialized by '' or 0 in case of number
like this :

```
const [numeroCommande, setNumeroCommande] = useState('');
    const [dateCommande, setDateCommande] = useState('2023-01-01');
    const [client, setClient] = useState('');
    const [totalHT, setTotalHT] = useState(0);
    const [detailsArray, setDetailsArray] = useState([
        {
            produit: '',
            quantite: 0,
            prixUnitaire: 0,
        },
    ]);
```

and btw in the data base this is a one to many relation that's why im using the fieldArray for the "many"
however for the initial values of formik here it is
(i did not include the ids because they are auto generated)

```
const initialDetails = detailsArray.map(detail => ({
        produit: detail.produit,
        quantite: detail.quantite,
        prixUnitaire: detail.prixUnitaire,
    }));

    const initialValues = {
        numeroCommande,
        dateCommande,
        client,
        totalHT,
        details: detailsArray.length > 0 ? detailsArray : initialDetails,
    };
```

here is the form

```
<Formik
                        onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
                        initialValues={initialValues}
                        validationSchema={checkoutSchema}
                        enableReinitialize
                    >
                        {({
                              values,
                              errors,
                              touched,
                              handleBlur,
                              handleChange,
                              handleSubmit,
                              setFieldValue,
                          }) => (
                            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                <Box
                                    display="grid"
                                    gap="30px"
                                    sx={{
                                        "& > div": { gridColumn: isNonMobile ? undefined : "span 4" },
                                    }}
                                    >
                                    <Box
                                        display="grid"
                                        gap="30px"
                                        gridTemplateColumns="repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))"
                                        sx={{
                                            "& > div": { gridColumn: isNonMobile ? undefined : "span 4" },
                                        }}>
                                <Box mb={2}>
                                    <TextField
                                        type="text"
                                        name="numeroCommande"
                                        label="Numero Commande"
                                        variant="filled"
                                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        value={values.numeroCommande}
                                        error={touched.numeroCommande && !!errors.numeroCommande}
                                        helperText={touched.numeroCommande && errors.numeroCommande}
                                        sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                                        fullWidth
                                    />
                                </Box>
                                <Box mb={2}>
                                    <TextField
                                        type="date"
                                        name="dateCommande"
                                        label="Date Commande"
                                        fullWidth
                                        variant="filled"
                                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        value={values.dateCommande}
                                        error={touched.dateCommande && !!errors.dateCommande}
                                        helperText={touched.dateCommande && errors.dateCommande}
                                        sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                                    />
                                </Box>
                                <Box mb={2}>
                                    <TextField
                                        type="text"
                                        name="client"
                                        label="Client"
                                        fullWidth
                                        variant="filled"
                                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        value={values.client}
                                        error={touched.client && !!errors.client}
                                        helperText={touched.client && errors.client}
                                        sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                                    />
                                </Box>
                                <Box mb={2}>
                                    <TextField
                                        type="number"
                                        name="totalHT"
                                        label="Total HT"
                                        fullWidth
                                        variant="filled"
                                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        value={values.totalHT}
                                        error={touched.totalHT && !!errors.totalHT}
                                        helperText={touched.totalHT && errors.totalHT}
                                        sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                                    />
                                </Box>
                                    </Box>
                                    <FieldArray name="details">
                                        {({ push, remove }) => (
                                            <>
                                                {values.details.map((_, index) => (
                                                    <div key={index} className="mb-3">
                                                        <div className="row">
                                                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                                                <TextField
                                                                    type="text"
                                                                    name={`details[${index}].produit`}
                                                                    label="Produit"
                                                                    fullWidth
                                                                    variant="filled"
                                                                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                                                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                                                    value={values.details[index].produit}
                                                                    sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                                                                />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                                                <TextField
                                                                    type="number"
                                                                    name={`details[${index}].quantite`}
                                                                    label="Quantite"
                                                                    fullWidth
                                                                    variant="filled"
                                                                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                                                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                                                    value={values.details[index].quantite}
                                                                    sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                                                                />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                                                <TextField
                                                                    type="number"
                                                                    name={`details[${index}].prixUnitaire`}
                                                                    label="Prix Unitaire"
                                                                    fullWidth
                                                                    variant="filled"
                                                                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                                                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                                                    value={values.details[index].prixUnitaire}
                                                                    sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                                                                />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div className="mt-2">
                                                            {index > 0 && (
                                                                <Button
                                                                    sx={{m: 2}}
                                                                    variant="outlined"
                                                                    color="error"
                                                                    onClick={() => remove(index)}
                                                                >
                                                                    Remove
                                                                </Button>
                                                            )}
                                                            {index === values.details.length - 1 && (
                                                                <Button
                                                                    sx={{m: 2}}
                                                                    variant="outlined"
                                                                    color="success"
                                                                    onClick={() => push({ produit: '', quantite: 0, prixUnitaire: 0 })}
                                                                >
                                                                    Add More
                                                                </Button>
                                                            )}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                ))}
                                            </>
                                        )}
                                    </FieldArray>


                                </Box>
                                <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                                    <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={handleFormSubmit}>
                                        Submit
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button
                                        onClick={cancel}
                                        color="error"
                                        variant="contained"
                                        style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
                                    >
                                        Cancel
                                    </Button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        )}
                    </Formik>
```

for some reason the submit button doest send the results so i had to use onClick={handleFormSubmit} in the button

and for the handleFormSubmit function i took the values and convert them to a json format to send them to the data base

```
const handleFormSubmit = (values) => {
        console.log(values);
        saveOrUpdateBonDeCommande(values);
    };

    const saveOrUpdateBonDeCommande = (values) => {
        const {
            numeroCommande,
            dateCommande,
            client,
            totalHT,
            details,
        } = values;

        console.log("details", details);

        // The object to be sent to the database
        const updatedBonDeCommande = {
            numeroCommande,
            dateCommande,
            client,
            totalHT,
            bonDeCommandeDetails: details.map(detail => ({
                produit: detail.produit,
                quantite: detail.quantite,
                prixUnitaire: detail.prixUnitaire,
            })),
        };
```

and that's when the log result is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iYdu.png)

i checked all the namings and the initializations but mostly i think the problem is with the submission of the form because for somereason i had to put it in the button

Comment: Can you add a sandbox with your code?